# Reflection matrix - are these two definitions equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, orthogonal-matrices, reflection

Are these two definitions of a reflection matrix Q equivalent (if and only if)?

Definition 1: $Q^TQ = I$ and $det(Q) = -1$

Definition 2: $Q = I-2nn^T$ where $n$ is a unit normal vector to the plane that reflects vectors.

It’s easy to show that definition 2 implies 1 (I’ve already done this - so please do not prove this part). But proving that definition 1 implies 2 seems much more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The result is wrong for real vector spaces with dimension $n>2$**

The orthogonal transformation

$$Q=
\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & -\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & 0\\
\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & 0\\
0 & 0 &-1
\end{pmatrix}$$

is such that $\det Q= - 1$. However, $Q$ is the not the matrix of a reflection ($Q$ has no fixed vector).

Comment: Beautiful answer. It might be worthwhile pointing out what this matrix does geometrically. It is the composition of a reflection in the xy-plane and a rotation over 45 degrees around the $z$-axis.From here it is easy to invent more counterexamples.

Comment: However the real important take-away I think is that, geometrically, condition $Q^TQ = I$ (for real vector spaces) means no more and no less than 'the linear transformation described by $Q$ respects all distances and (hence) angles'. The condition itself in turn implies that det = 1 or det = -1, so the second condition in definition 1 singles out 'half' of these rigid motions. However not all or them are reflections, as we can take a reflection and compose it with some random det 1 rigid transformation

Comment: Vincent, thank you for your response - your response clarified what I realised yesterday. That when the determinant is -1 it is not necessarily a reflection but a ‘improper rotation’ - a composition of a rotation and a reflection. While the above counter example does address question, it does not provide an explanation as to why!

Comment: @Christian The Wikipedia article will give you more background: [Orthogonal matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix). In particular, the canonical form chapter gives the general form of an orthogonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Take an odd permutation on  $n$ symbols for large $n$, for example three parallel transpositions for $n=6$ such as (12)(34)(56). The corresponding permutation matrix will be orthogonal  and have determinant $-1$.

Its eigen space corresponding  to $-1$ eigenvalue is 3-dimensional and hence not a reflection matrix.

Much easier to see that diagonal matrices with $\pm1$'s in the diagonal are orthogonal and among them $-1$ determinant is easy to find again providing counterexamples.

Third kind is: get many $2\times2$ reflection matrices, say 3 of them. Call them $A,B,C$.  Now construct a $6\times6$ matrix in block-diagonal form using $A,B,C$ as diagonal blocks.